# host system doesn't support vsock

Tags: kubernetes, virtual-machine, qemu, kernel-module, kata-containers

I'm studying about **Kata Container** using Nvidia **Jetson Nano** and want to make Kata Container work on Jetson device.

OS is **ubuntu 18.04** and installed docker, k8s and kata container. And I tried to make pod using kata container, but error occured.

```
Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: /etc/kata-containers/configuration.toml: host system doesn't support vsock: stat /dev/vhost-vsock: no such file or directory: unknown
```

I thought that kata container uses VM(I don't know exactly...) and my device doesn't have vhost-vsock module.

so I tried

```
modprobe /dev/vhost-vsock
```

but it doesn't work.

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module /dev/vhost-vsock not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.253-tegra
```

and I tried

```
lsmod | grep vhost
```

there's nothing...

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.